# jquery ajax json request error when usin echo

Tags: php, jquery, json, request

i have this code:

```
$.ajax({
          url: 'urlsubmit.php',
          data: json_data,
          dataType: 'json',
          type: 'POST',
          success: function(data) {
                            $('#saveResult_'+tnTopic_id).html("OK");
            if(data.indexOf("ok") !== -1) {
                $("#saveResult_"+tnTopic_id).html("Ok, am salvat!");
            }
            else {
                $("#saveResult_"+tnTopic_id ).html(data);
                //alert("A aparut o eroare:\n\r"+data);
            }
          },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    $('#saveResult_'+tnTopic_id).html(textStatus + ' | ' + errorThrown + ' | ' + jqXHR.responseText);
                    //alert(xhr.status);
                    //alert(thrownError);
                  }           
        }); 
}
```

and in urlsubmit.php i have only echo "ok"

and i got this error parsererror | SyntaxError: Unexpected token o

Answer (score 3):

remove this - (*if you are not responding with json*)

```
dataType: 'json',
```

jQuery is trying to parse `ok` as json, that is why you are getting that error

Comment: dataType: 'json', ... it  is there

Comment: @Zvunks He's saying to remove it, `dataType` is to tell jQuery what type of data to respect as a response. Because you specify `json`, it's trying to parse it as `json` - `"ok"` is not valid json and is throwing an error. If you remove the `dataType` attribute it will autoguess.

Comment: If you really want to send json data, use 'echo json_encode($your_variable);' from your PHP